# @reboot is not working in CRON

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to run a shell-script and a command at the start of my Ubuntu server.

Here is my `CRON`

```
@reboot /home/steam/check.sh
@reboot screen -d -S up -m node /var/www/html/Up1/server/server.js
```

What I'm getting in the logs:
`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

```
Jul 19 19:48:28 vc1s cron[3185]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jul 19 19:48:28 vc1s cron[3185]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jul 19 19:48:28 vc1s CRON[3209]: (root) CMD (screen -d -S up -m node /var/www/html/Up1/server/server.js)
Jul 19 19:48:28 vc1s CRON[3211]: (root) CMD (/home/steam/check.sh)
Jul 19 19:51:20 vc1s cron[3779]: (CRON) DEATH (can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 3185: Resource temporarily unavailable)
Jul 19 19:55:01 vc1s CRON[3996]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

My `check.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

until screen -d -S unturned -m /home/steam/start.sh; do
        echo "Server 'myserver' crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
        sleep 1
done
```

My `start.sh`. It's for launching an Unturned game server. I don't think this script is important but I guess I should show you.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script starts a Unturned 3 server on Linux machines
# Syntax: start.sh <instance name>
# Author: fr34kyn01535

#CONFIG
INSTANCE_NAME=1
STEAMCMD_HOME="./steamcmd"
UNTURNED_HOME="./unturned"

#COLORS
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
YELLLOW='\033[0;33m'
NC='\033[0m'

#Steam checks
STEAMCMD_API=$STEAMCMD_HOME/linux32/steamclient.so
UNTURNED_API=$UNTURNED_HOME/Unturned_Data/Plugins/x86/steamclient.so
printf "Steam: "
if [ -f $STEAMCMD_API ]; then
        if diff $STEAMCMD_API $UNTURNED_API >/dev/null ; then
                printf "${GREEN}UP TO DATE${NC}\n\n"
        else
                cp $STEAMCMD_API $UNTURNED_API
                printf "${YELLLOW}UPDATING${NC}\n\n"
        fi
else
        printf "${RED}NOT FOUND${NC}\n\n"
fi

cd $UNTURNED_HOME

if [ -f RocketLauncher.exe ]; then
        ulimit -n 2048
        mono RocketLauncher.exe $INSTANCE_NAME
else
        echo "RocketLauncher not found."
fi
```

The thing is that if I execute `./check.sh` from `/home/steam` It works fine. The bad news is that the `@reboot` doesn't work for me when I reboot my VPS.

`screen -list` doesn't throw anything if I reboot.

I've tried multiple things but didn't work, the last thing I changed was adding `-d` parameter in the `screen` commands so the server wouldn't need a `terminal` to write down the start-up.

I'm not sure how much can be done here to make `@reboot` work as expected.

**How can I make my scripts run on boot? Are there any other alternatives to `CRON`'s `@reboot`?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried adding `sleep 60;` before the command at @reboot, didn't work either. I've tried also `@reboot root /home/steam/check.sh`

Comment: I think you should be solving this problem using a systemd-based service. You get automatic restarts, proper storage of logging as well as running at boot for "free".

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just read about `systemd` in Wikipedia but do you mind explaining this in more detail focusing on my problem? I just feel too lost in this area.

Comment: I was mostly suggesting this to find out whether the version of ubuntu you are using has systemd at all. Please check that, for example by checking whether you have the systemctl executable on your system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the systemd.service manpage. It describes how to configure systemd to manage a service. I am sure you will find examples for your system in `/usr/lib/systemd/system` or similar paths.

In your case, the service would look somewhat like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Unturned Game Server

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/steam/start.sh
Type=simple
User=steam
Group=steam
WorkingDirectory=/home/steam
Restart=on-failure
```

Put this in a file `/etc/systemd/system/unturned.service`. Then run `systemctl daemon-reload` (once, and whenever you change `unturned.service` to tell systemd to re-read the configuration) and `systemctl start unturned.service` to start the game server.

If that works as expected, you can use `systemctl enable unturned.service` to make sure it starts at boot.

A few notes on the options used:

- If start.sh is not supposed to run as user/group `steam`, edit appropriately.
- `WantedBy` in the `Install` section tells systemd which "target" (see man systemd.target) pulls the service in when you enable it using systemctl enable.
- `Restart` defines under which circumstances systemd will automatically restart the service. There are more restart-related options, which you may or may not want to change; see the systemd.service man page.

Comment: Looking nice, I'll check this tomorrow as soon as I can, and if it works check the answer as valid. Thanks.

Comment: It worked for all my scripts ❤, I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04

Comment: If more people are wondering on how to delete a service. http://superuser.com/questions/513159/how-to-remove-systemd-services#936976

Answer (score 31):

Try `man 5 crontab`. If your crontab supported, you should see @reboot, @yearly, @monthly,.,,,

then try add some sleep for moment may can help.

```
@reboot sleep 60;/root/s3-mount.sh
```

Comment: This did the trick for me, thank you for this simple solution

Answer (score 1):

Check the critical-chain for crond.service, as asked and answered in [This StackExchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165270/centos-7-boots-too-fast-and-network-is-not-ready-when-executing-cron-scripts)

Also, reference [this FreeDesktop article](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) addressing this issue.

In general, systemd is configured to have very limited dependencies, starting many daemons in parallel to reduce time spent booting.  Services that are not necessarily dependent on the network being fully up and functional will fail if there are components that assume the network is in a stable state.  Failures such as this may be difficult to diagnose, but using `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `journalctl -xel` output can lead you to the root cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had a script in **/usr/local/bin** and tried to do **@reboot namescript**
it was enough to enter the full path **@reboot /usr/local/bin/namescript**