# Configure systemd to manage a service

Tags: bash, cron, ubuntu-18.04, systemd

I'm trying to run a bash script on boot up.

I tried using the following in crontab:

```
@reboot bash /home/me/apod.sh
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465751/reboot-is-not-working-in-cron) with a similar issue. I tried to follow the instructions of the accepted answer. I.e. I made a file `/etc/systemd/system/apod.service` which has the contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Set APOD as Desktop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/me/apod.sh
Type=simple
User=me
```

and then tried `systemctl start apod.service` and it worked as expected.

I then did `systemctl enable apod.service` to make sure that it runs at boot. But it still doesn't. I'm not sure if I don't have the right permissions for it to run?

My `/etc/systemd/system/apod.service` file permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 206 Jun  1 10:52 /etc/systemd/system/apod.service
```

---

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I have also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59930236/systemd-enabled-services-not-starting-at-boot-anymore) which might be relevant but doesn't seem to have an answer. It's seems surprisingly difficult to get a script to run on boot!

---

When I run `systemctl status apod` after boot:

```
● apod.service - Set APOD as Desktop
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/apod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2021-06-01 12:02:17 BST; 1min 31s ago
  Process: 817 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/me/apod.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 817 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 01 12:02:17 me-XPS-15-9500 bash[817]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
Jun 01 12:02:17 me-XPS-15-9500 bash[817]:     '_open', req)
Jun 01 12:02:17 me-XPS-15-9500 bash[817]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
Jun 01 12:02:17 me-XPS-15-9500 bash[817]:     result = func(*args)
Jun 01 12:02:17 me-XPS-15-9500 bash[817]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1248, in https_open
Jun 01 12:02:17 me-XPS-15-9500 bash[817]:     context=self._context)
Jun 01 12:02:17 me-XPS-15-9500 bash[817]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1205, in do_open
Jun 01 12:02:17 me-XPS-15-9500 bash[817]:     raise URLError(err)
Jun 01 12:02:17 me-XPS-15-9500 bash[817]: urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
Jun 01 12:02:17 me-XPS-15-9500 gsettings[1077]: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

---

[Here is a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722352/bash-script-not-executing-on-startup) I made that is relevant.

---

My shell script (`/home/me/apod.sh`):

```sh
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                 

export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus"

python /home/me/apod.py

/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/me/Downloads/apod.jpg"
```

and the python script it calls (`/home/me/apod.py`):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML
import requests
import subprocess
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen('https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html')
soup = BSHTML(page,features="html.parser")
images = soup.findAll('img')

url = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/'+images[0]['src']
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
with open('/home/me/Downloads/apod.jpg',"w") as f:
            f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Please, say me what is the output of `systemctl status apod` after booting...

Comment: I will post as an edit to my question :)

Comment: As you can see systemd tries to start your service, but an error occurs.

Comment: There is a call to run a python script in my bash script. It seems like that is where it is failing. But I don't understand why the script runs perfectly if I run it manually or if I do `systemctl start apod.service`.

Comment: Are you using relative paths in the `apod.sh` script?

Comment: Yes. And the script runs fine when I run it manually. I'll add the script to my question though. Thanks.

Comment: Does it also run fine when called from another folder?

Comment: It does if I run `/bin/bash /home/me/apod.sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting my findings as an answer since it's too large for a comment.

---

Lets take a look at the error shown by `systemctl status apod` **after boot**:

> urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>

This implies that the `requests.get()` call fails.

This makes sense, since your systemd script is called **before the machine has an active network connection**. Therefore, the request will always fail, resulting in an error.

I'd recommend adding an `Wants` / `After` `network-online.target` to ensure the systemd script is started when the machine has an active network connection:

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
```

- [Cause a systemd script to execute after networking has started?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started)

Comment: It did work once but now I'm having trouble with it again. When I run `systemctl status apod` I get `Jun 03 18:17:01 systemd[1]: Started Set APOD as Desktop.
Jun 03 18:17:03 gsettings[1584]: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: No such file or directory`

Comment: Do I need to also make the systemd script wait until all the files are available before it tries to set the desktop background using one of those files?

Comment: That error sounds more of a gsettings specific error. I'm not that familiar with that. Maybe [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237805/help-with-creating-systemd-timers-to-automate-window-theme-changes) could be useful. Or try using google some more, maybe check if the user from which systemd starts the script hasn't the right permissions?